# Stored procedure parameters with literals not working in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a stored procedure that takes two parameters as `varchar(50)`. The stored procedure does a few simple queries into a temp table and the returns the result set from the temp table (I removed the actual queries)

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[cv_GetBooks]
    @bookNumber as varchar(50),
    @bookDate as varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    --a few select statements

    if @ismultiple = '0'
    begin
         select * from books where bookNumber = @bookNumber
    and bookDate = @bookDate
    and Bookname is  not null
    end
    ELSE
    Begin
        select * into #temp from books
    where bookNumber = @bookNumber
    and bookDate = @bookDate
    and Bookname is   null

           select * from books
    where bookauthor not in (select bookauthor from #temp) 
    and bookNumber= @bookNumber
            and bookDate= @bookDate
        drop table #temp
    end
END
```

I have this query installed on my local development machine on SQL Server 2008. I have also installed it on a two test machines running Windows Server 2003 and SQL Server 2008. The stored procedure has been working as expected.

```
cv_GetBooks '012345678', '06062012' --returns result set as expected
```

I recently moved it to a test server in another remote environment that is running Windows server 2008 and SQL Server 2008 R2. The stored procedure no longer works as expected. After running SQL Profiler I have confirmed that the same code is being executed:

```
cv_GetBooks '012345678', '06062012' --run on SQL server 2008 r2 returns nothing
```

When I removed the quotes from the query I got the expected result:

```
cv_GetBooks 012345678, 06062012 --run with out quotes server returns expected result set
```

I have since installed the same stored procedure on local version of SQL Server 2008 R2 and everything is running as expected, with the literal string quotes in place, as in the first example.

At first I thought it was an escape issue with the passed parameters but that doesn't seem correct because the passed values are do not contain any single quotes.

Having installed and had it working on so many environments, I am under the impression that this is maybe a setting in SQL Server that I am unaware of.

What could be causing the stored procedure to not return the result set with the string literals in place on the SQL Server 2008 r2 instance, but work correctly with out them there?

Comment: What are the data types of the columns? Why have you hidden the where clause (seems to be more relevant to the question than a seemingly needless reference to a temp table).

Comment: Your second parameter looks like something that should be a `date`. If it is compared against a datetime/date column you may get different result depending on the `dateformat` setting. If it is a date you could try to change the datatype of the parameter to date and pass the parameter as `YYYYMMDD`.

Comment: Temp tables created inside a stored proc are automatically dropped when the stored proc returns - there's no need to do it manually.

Comment: Plus in addition to @Damien_The_Unbeliever's comment it can actually be beneficial to *not* drop them, even though that flies in the face of most development principles. In this case leaving the #temp table alone will allow the engine to potentially re-use the metadata and cause less locking within tempdb if this same #temp table is created again before its deferred drop occurs.

Comment: Can I ask again, what are the data types of the columns?

Comment: Thanks for the advice on the temp tables.  I have updated the stored procedure to include the where statements.  @Mikael Eriksson The second parameter is a date but the date and the book number are stored as varchar in the database table because of an external requirement beyond my control, so I don't think there is a conversion issue with the 'dateformat' setting

Comment: @AaronBertrand The booknumber and bookdate in the table are both varchar. The same as the input parameters.

Comment: @jsturtevant, did you check the machine they are not working on for the data types? Is it possible that they are differnt between the two servers? And I would not store dates as varchar, that causes isssues when you want to do date calulations. Use date or datetime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not post the table definition of table Books, but

```
cv_GetBooks '012345678', '06062012' 
--run on SQL server 2008 r2 returns nothing

cv_GetBooks 012345678, 06062012 
--run with out quotes server returns expected result set
```

could be caused if BookNumber and BookDate were numeric rather than varchar:

Leading zero in ints is dropped, and when converted to varchar the resulting string does not contain the leading zero.

It's also not clear how the data in your table affects the execution (IF statement!) in your code.

Answer (score 2):

This might not be the exact answer, but try this as a way to finding out more about the problem. Run some basic queries (not the whole proc) in SSMS, with the parameters in place, such as:

(I'm not sure where @ismultiple comes from - doesn't seem to be declared or parameterised?)

```
select * 
from books
where bookNumber = '012345678'
and bookDate = '06062012'
and Bookname is null
```

and

```
select * 
from books
where bookNumber = 012345678
and bookDate = 06062012
and Bookname is null
```

Do you get the same results? What results do you get?

My suspicion is the data types: Somewhere something is being converted, and therefore not working in one environment but working in another (where the data type is different or the SQL version doesn't convert automatically). EG: 012345678 could be being converted to 12345678 if the data is stored in the table as a numeric data type. But try and isolate the behaviour without the stored procedure and/or the temp table, that might help narrow the possible causes down...